# Bootstrap make left column go below when stacking

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a page with the following structure:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"> LEFT </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"> CENTER </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"> RIGHT </div>
</div>
```

that results in something like

```
LEFT            CENTER             RIGHT
```

However, in smaller screens I want them to stack as

```
CENTER
LEFT
RIGHT
```

Can I achieve this in Bootstrap? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since rows use flexbox, you can use the [**`order`**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/#order) utilities (`order-md` for the `md` break).

Here the base order is `2-1-3` and becomes `1-2-3` at `md` and above:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 order-2 order-md-1"> LEFT </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 order-1 order-md-2"> CENTER </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 order-3 order-md-3"> RIGHT </div>
</div>
```